# Scala: Why does fixing a type member create a Java subclass?

Tags: scala

Whenever the class

```
class X {
 type T
}
```

is instantiated while fixing the type member a new Java class is created:

```
scala> new X() { type T = Int }.getClass.hashCode
res5: Int = 2033908791

scala> new X() { type T = Int }.getClass.hashCode
res6: Int = 1820034148
```

Yet, when a factory is used

```
object X {
  def apply[TP] = new X { type T = TP }
}
```

then a single Java class is capable of representing all possible instances:

```
scala> X.apply[Int].getClass.hashCode
res7: Int = 45806309

scala> X.apply[String].getClass.hashCode
res8: Int = 45806309
```

Is there are reason for that behaviour or does the Scala compiler simply lack the sensible optimization that a single class would suffice?

It seems that this behaviour is another difference between classes with type members and classes with type parameters (`class Y[T]`):

```
scala> class Y[T]
defined class Y

scala> new Y[Int].getClass.hashCode
res9: Int = 1364679843

scala> new Y[String].getClass.hashCode
res10: Int = 1364679843
```

Answer (score 7):

Every expression of the form `new Something(someArgs) { /* other defs, whether overriding or not */ }` defines a statically distinct type, even if they're structurally equivalent.

On the other hand, evaluating any single such expression multiple times instantiates the same anonymous class.

It has nothing to do with the existence of an abstract type member.

Comment: Ok, this is the observed behaviour. I added the abstract type because I sometimes use this mechanism to reflect the internal state of instances in the type system (cf. type safe builder pattern). I wanted to know if there is a reason for that behaviour and if it might be worth to avoid the creation of some unnecessary classes using a factory.